# "E: Unable to locate package mana-toolkit" when running install mana-toolkit on Kali

Tags: kali-linux

While installing `mana-toolkit` on my VirtualBox Kali machine, I'm getting this:

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install -f mana-toolkit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mana-toolkit
```

Comment: Related: https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/mana-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

You can still find on Github [The MANA Toolkit](https://github.com/sensepost/mana).

Quote:

> At Defcon 26 we talked about how we're deprecating mana-toolkit in favour of 
>   [bettercap](http://bettercap.org/) and [berate-ap](https://github.com/sensepost/berate_ap). The core of mana, [hostapd-mana](https://github.com/sensepost/hostapd-mana) is still under active development. This repo isn't going anywhere, and can still be used, but it hasn't been actively maintained for some time. Keep an eye on [w1f1.net](https://w1f1.net/) for more info.

The MANA Toolkit is no longer in the repository, since this package had been
superseded by newer packages.

You should try to move on to one of the replacements of the MANA Toolkit,
or you could try to install it from source by downloading from Github.

Answer (score 0):

```
kali@kali:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

A prompt will open. Type:

```
#
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Save this in the prompt and continue:

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt update
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```